# How many banner ads that must be placed in the application

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I have application for photos in The main facade I put one ads banner and one at the entrance to the image I want to put two units Is this allowed and you can use the same ads code for that

Comment: banner are the most annoying thing ever. if you want someone to use your app, avoid using them in avery pages and avoid two ads in the same page. I don't know if it's allowed but I think that google might answer you. I'm sure that even if it is possible, two are a bad choice

Comment: And this is what I thought thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [Banner ad guidance](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287) from Google. There are instructions and examples with best practices.